# Break for-of loop when promise never resolves

Tags: javascript

I have this code that loops through an array of async functions (`async` functions and functions that return promises), calls each function, awaits for its result, logs to the console, and proceeds to the next one. This works fine unless someone forgets to resolve/reject their promise. The app would halt without any indication other than the logs have stopped printing.

```js
(async function() {

  var foo = [
    async() => 1,
    () => Promise.resolve(2),
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {}), // This will cause it to stop
    async() => 3,
    () => Promise.resolve(4),
  ]

  for (const bar of foo) {
    const baz = await bar()
    // does not proceed if bar doesn't resolve/reject.
    console.log(baz)
  }

})()
```

Is there a way to set a natively set a timeout? Or maybe break the loop? Tell the runtime to shoot a warning perhaps? Or must this timeout/breaking/warning be done by custom? The code is written in Node primarily, but I think this could also apply to browser JS.

Comment: Have you looked at Promise.all() ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all It looks like you're trying to have a bunch of promise work together.

Comment: "*Is there a way to set a natively set a timeout? Tell the runtime to shoot a warning perhaps?*" No, there's not. Notice that there are also sometimes promises that are intentionally never resolved, it's handy from time to time. One can't tell them apart from those that are hanging unintentionally.

Comment: "*The code is written in Node primarily*" - if one of the functions forgot to continue after its asynchronous task, e.g. by not adding an event listener to it, a node script will halt when there are no events (and event sources) left to process. So yes, that would "break" from your loop. Depends on what else is going on in your program of course.